# One Wire DS2408 set state

Tags: lua, nodemcu

today I tried to work with a DS2408 and dev NodeMCU.
https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2408.pdf
I used https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-ds2408/blob/master/DS2408/DS2408.cpp as example.

```
local pin = 3
local addr = '29-example'
local DS2408_CHANNEL_WRITE_CMD   = 0x5A

function set_state(state)
    ow.setup(pin)

    if (ow.reset(pin) == 1) then
        ow.select(pin, addr)
        ow.write(pin, DS2408_CHANNEL_WRITE_CMD, 1)
        ow.write(pin, state, 1)
        ow.write(pin, bit.bnot(state), 1)

        if (ow.read(pin) == 0xAA) then
            if (ow.read(pin) == state) then
                return true
            end
        end
    else
        return false
    end
end

print(set_state(0x02))
```

Setting the state works ok. After it is set, One Wire sends a 0xAA to confirm (Works) and the next byte is the state what the IOs currently have.
As you can see I compare the 2nd byte with the original state in my code.
I always get 0x0 as 2nd byte what is wrong...

Anyone any idea what is going on?

Kind regards,
Marco

Comment: Ask [there](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino+1-wire).

Comment: I don't know if that matters, but in Lua `bit.bnot` may return negative values.  To enforce the usual interval 0..255, you should do `bit.bnot(state) % 256`.